# chef-server-ctl reconfigure fails after customizing the PostgreSQL port

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra

I'm using Open Source Chef 11.0.10 on Ubuntu 12.04.  This is a shared server where PostgreSQL and Apache are already running, so I'm trying to customize the Chef port numbers.

I've created the file /etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb, which contains the lines:

```
nginx['ssl_port'] = 8443
postgresql['port'] = 5433
```

When I execute the command:

```
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

it fails on the line:

```
execute[/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef] action run
```

and the error message says:

```
---- Begin output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
---- End output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef ----
```

Now, the Chef instance of PostgreSQL does appear to be running, in addition to the original instance:

```
$ ps -ef | grep postgresql | grep -v grep
postgres  1000     1  0 09:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
root      4830  4421  0 09:46 ?        00:00:00 runsv postgresql
root      4831  4830  0 09:46 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/chef-server/postgresql
998       5579  4830  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/postgres -D /var/opt/chef-server/postgresql/data
```

What did I miss?

**More details:**

I had used the omnibus package to do the initial chef-server install:

```
https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/chef-server_11.0.10-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb
```

It failed before completion at the same step with the same error because it's trying to use the default PostgreSQL port, which is already in use.

And the Chef PostgreSQL instance is running:

```
$ sudo /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/sv status postgresql
run: postgresql: (pid 5579) 86034s; run: log: (pid 4831) 86158s
```

Comment: Does that user have permission to create the db?

Comment: Well, I can't seem to connect to the Chef PostgreSQL instance to determine if the opscode_chef user exists.  The command "psql -p 5433 -U postgres" returns the error "Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket '/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433'" even though I've configured that instance to write its pid and socket file to /var/run/postgresql-chef/.  Any tips would help!

Comment: I meant opscode_chef "database".  I'm trying to use psql to connect to the Chef PostgreSQL instance with the "postgres" user (which is usually the default db user), so I can list the databases.

Comment: I gave up trying to get Chef's PostgreSQL instance using a different port.  Instead, I modified the default PostgreSQL installation's port number to be 5433 and let Chef's use 5432.  Now the "chef-server-ctl reconfigure" command completes successfully.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question

Comment: ok, will do.  I hadn't done that because I really haven't answered the underlying question, I just found a workaround for it.

Answer (score 4):

I gave up trying to get Chef's PostgreSQL instance configured to use a different port.

Instead, I modified our existing PostgreSQL installation's port number to be 5433 and let Chef's instance use 5432.  Now the "chef-server-ctl reconfigure" command completes successfully.

Comment: very sad this this is still an issue :(

Answer (score 1):

check postgresql log file

```
tail -f /var/log/chef-server/postgresql/current
```

> 2015-02-28_13:29:01.48646 FATAL:  could not create lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
>   2015-02-28_13:29:02.57961 FATAL:  could not create lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
>   2015-02-28_13:29:02.57961 FATAL:  could not create lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied

My problem is solve  running following command

```
chmod 777 /tmp
```

Comment: Yes, because yours is a different issue - "could not create lock file" while the original issue is "could not connect to database".
Permission denied vs Connection (socket) problem.